# Get image used by MLKitAnalyzer

Tags: android, image, android-camerax, google-mlkit

MLKitAnalyzer as used below will present found objects in the labels variable. But I also need access to the image that these labels were based upon. I want to do further analysis of the image used by MLKitAnalyzer, as described [here][1]. How can I access the image?

```
// ***************** Analyze with MLKit imageLabeler
val options = ImageLabelerOptions.Builder()
    .setConfidenceThreshold(0.7f)
    .build()
val imageLabeler = ImageLabeling.getClient(options)
val detectors = listOf(imageLabeler)
val analyzer = MlKitAnalyzer(
    detectors,
    ImageAnalysis.COORDINATE_SYSTEM_ORIGINAL,
    executor
)
{
    val labels = it.getValue(imageLabeler)
    if (labels.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        return@MlKitAnalyzer
    }
    var result = ""
    for (label in labels) {
        val text = label.text
        val confidence = (label.confidence * 100).toInt()
        val index = label.index
        result = result + text + " " + confidence + "%\n"
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "*****************Image Labelling result $result")
}
val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
    // Default is OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_YUV_420_888
    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
    .build()
imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, analyzer)


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77795598/using-two-camerax-imageanalysis-analyzers?noredirect=1#comment137150195_77795598
```

Comment: What is MLKitAnalizer analyzing?

Answer (score 2):

Note, the previous answer has been edited because it seems like `MlKitAnalyzer` closes the image internally after getting result from the last detector, so setting own `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer` to pass the `ImageProxy` to `MlKitAnalyzer` yourself won't work.

---

One way is saving the required data from `Image` somewhere before passing it to `MlKitAnalyzer` and matching with the timestamp (previous answer suggested using the image directly but it would be closed when `MlKitAnalyzer` provides the result).

Another option (probably more efficient or maybe even easier) is implementing a `Detector` yourself and passing it to `MlKitAnalyzer` so that you can get the `Image` before `MlKitAnalyzer` closes it.

For that, the conversion APIs mentioned in [InputImage](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/common/InputImage) documentation can be very helpful.

```
val options = ImageLabelerOptions.Builder()
    .setConfidenceThreshold(0.7f)
    .build()
val imageLabeler = ImageLabeling.getClient(options)

val imagePassingDetector = object: Detector<Image> {
    override fun close() {}

    override fun getDetectorType() = TYPE_IMAGE_LABELING

    override fun process(bitmap: Bitmap, rotationDegrees: Int): Task<Image> {
        return processInputImage(InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, rotationDegrees))
    }

    override fun process(image: Image, rotationDegrees: Int): Task<Image> {
        return processInputImage(InputImage.fromMediaImage(image, rotationDegrees))
    }

    override fun process(
        image: Image,
        rotationDegrees: Int,
        coordinatesMatrix: Matrix
    ): Task<Image> {
        return processInputImage(
            InputImage.fromMediaImage(
                image,
                rotationDegrees,
                coordinatesMatrix
            )
        )
    }

    override fun process(
        byteBuffer: ByteBuffer,
        width: Int,
        height: Int,
        rotationDegrees: Int,
        format: Int
    ): Task<Image> {
        return processInputImage(
            InputImage.fromByteBuffer(
                byteBuffer,
                width,
                height,
                rotationDegrees,
                format
            )
        )
    }

    private fun processInputImage(inputImage: InputImage): Task<Image> {
        return processImage(inputImage.mediaImage)
    }

    private fun processImage(image: Image?): Task<Image> {
        // Do further processing of the Image from here

        Log.d("MlKitFragment", "image = $image")
        Log.d("MlKitFragment", "image planes = ${image?.planes}")

        return Tasks.forResult(image)
    }
}

val detectors = listOf(imageLabeler, imagePassingDetector)
val analyzer = MlKitAnalyzer(
    detectors,
    ImageAnalysis.COORDINATE_SYSTEM_ORIGINAL,
    executor
)
{
    val labels = it.getValue(imageLabeler)
    if (labels.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        return@MlKitAnalyzer
    }
    var result = ""
    for (label in labels) {
        val text = label.text
        val confidence = (label.confidence * 100).toInt()
        val index = label.index
        result = result + text + " " + confidence + "%\n"
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "*****************Image Labelling result $result")
}
val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
    // Default is OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_YUV_420_888
    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
    .build()
imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, analyzer)
```

PS: While this answers this specific question, I am not quite sure about your original question [1]. It seems you not only require two separate `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer`s there, but actually two `ImageAnalysis` use cases because you need YUV format in one and RGBA format in another. Probably, you can instead try to find out how to convert the YUV format into RGBA.